# CSV Check columns before show HTML Table with PHP

Tags: php, csv

i don`t know how i validate some infos before show in HTML Table.

This is the functions to check .csv datas.

```
function validaCPF($input){

$c = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $input);

if (strlen($c) != 11 || preg_match("/^{$c[0]}{11}$/", $c))
    return false;

for ($s = 10, $n = 0, $i = 0; $s >= 2; $n += $c[$i++] * $s--);

if ($c[9] != ((($n %= 11) < 2) ? 0 : 11 - $n))
    return false;

for ($s = 11, $n = 0, $i = 0; $s >= 2; $n += $c[$i++] * $s--);

if ($c[10] != ((($n %= 11) < 2) ? 0 : 11 - $n))
    return false;
return true;
```

}

```
function validaEmail($email) {

$conta = "^[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+@";
$domino = "[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+.";
$extensao = "([a-zA-Z]{2,4})$";

$pattern = $conta.$domino.$extensao;
  if (ereg($pattern, $email))
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

}

```
function ValidaData($data){
// data é menor que 8
if ( strlen($data) < 8){
    return false;
}else{
    // verifica se a data possui
    // a barra (/) de separação
    if(strpos($data, "/") !== FALSE){
        //
        $partes = explode("/", $data);
        // pega o dia da data
        $dia = $partes[0];
        // pega o mês da data
        $mes = $partes[1];
        // prevenindo Notice: Undefined offset: 2
        // caso informe data com uma única barra (/)
        $ano = isset($partes[2]) ? $partes[2] : 0;

        if (strlen($ano) < 4) {
            return false;
        } else {
            // verifica se a data é válida
            if (checkdate($mes, $dia, $ano)) {
                 return true;
            } else {
                 return false;
            }
        }
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

I wanna check the entire .CSV file and after that display the informations in my HTML Table.

The code below is what i`m using to display my .csv

$row = 1;

if (($handle = fopen("pacientes.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) { 
    echo '';

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    if ($row == 1) {
        echo '<thead><tr>';
    }else{
        echo '<tr>';
    }

    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
```

// enter the validation here, to check columns.

```
        if(empty($data[$c])) {
           $value = "&nbsp;";
        }else{
           $value = $data[$c];
        }
        if ($row == 1) {
            echo '<th>'.$value.'</th>';
        }else{
            echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
        }
    }

    if ($row == 1) {
        echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';
    }else{
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    $row++;
```

}

```
echo '</tbody></table>';
fclose($handle);
```

}

CSV

```
"nome", "sobrenome", "email", "datanascimento", "genero", "tiposanguineo", "endereco", "cidade", "estado", "cep","cpf", "frkPlanoSaude"
"Kai", "Souza", "KaiCavalcantiSouza@teleworm.us", "10/14/2001", "M", "B+", "Servidão Edmundo Bittencourt 1123", "Florianópolis", "SC", "88048-379","77002286986", "345"
```

I wanna check columns email, data and cpf.

Comment: What is the issue you are having? What should this do vs. what does it do?

Comment: You should display in .csv only valid email, cpf, and data data.
I am not sure how to include validation functions within the code to display correctly.

Comment: I wanna do validation in my .csv to check every column with wrong data to display correctly.

Comment: I would validate this data as required before storing them, not displaying them, and for displaying them in HTML I will just use `htmlspecialchars()` and show whatever the data is.